# About vue.js v-card

Tags: vue.js

I'm learning vue.js now. There was a problem there. I want the v-card tag to display a video instead of an image, but it doesn't work.
Below is the code I wrote.

```
                            <v-card hover width="250">
                                <video height="350px" width="100%"
                                    src="******************">

                                    <v-card-title class="white--text mt-1">
                                        <p class="ml-1">
                                            name
                                        </p>
                                    </v-card-title>
                                </video>
                                <v-card-text>
                                    <div class="font-weight-bold ml-2 mb-1">
                                        subject
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="font-weight-bold ml-2 mb-2">
                                        text
                                    </div>
                                </v-card-text>
                                <v-card-actions class="justify-center">
                                    <v-btn height="40" width="130" depressed class="test2 mt-10 mb-10" color="teal">
                                        button
                                    </v-btn>
                                </v-card-actions>
                            </v-card>
```

Even if it can be displayed, there are extra margins on the left and right.css is not adapted. If anyone knows the cause, please let me know.

Comment: Please bring more information about the problem. can you upload an image from issue? You can add `controls` attribute to `video` tag to show the controls of video.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).